# Is it impossible to assign output argument after completion of recursive loop in the function of MATLAB?

Tags: function, recursion

When the below function is executed, I get the following error message "Output argument "max_idx" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "find_node"."
I think the problem is in the fact that some output is produced after recursive loop. How can I solve this?

```
function  max_idx = find_node(wt)
persistent all_idx_max;
node_degree=sum(wt,2);
maxval = max(node_degree);
all_nodes_with_max_val = ismember(node_degree,maxval);
idx_max = find(all_nodes_with_max_val); 
if isempty(all_idx_max)
all_idx_max=1:8;
end
if size(idx_max,1)==3
    max_idx=all_idx_max(idx_max(1))
elseif size(idx_max,1)>1
    all_idx_max=idx_max;
    find_node(wt(idx_max,idx_max));  <--problem happens in this path
else 
    max_idx=all_idx_max(idx_max)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add output to the recursive part

```
function  max_idx = find_node(wt)
persistent all_idx_max;
node_degree=sum(wt,2);
maxval = max(node_degree);
all_nodes_with_max_val = ismember(node_degree,maxval);
idx_max = find(all_nodes_with_max_val); 
if isempty(all_idx_max)
all_idx_max=1:8;
end
if size(idx_max,1)==3
    max_idx=all_idx_max(idx_max(1))
elseif size(idx_max,1)>1
    all_idx_max=idx_max;
    ***max_idx =*** find_node(wt(idx_max,idx_max));  <--problem happens in this path
else 
    max_idx=all_idx_max(idx_max)
end
```